# Extracting a word from Outlook Email Body while replying email with predefined Template

Tags: vba, outlook, oft

I have a working code which is extracting information from subject of initial email.

```
Sub InitialNotif()

Dim origEmail As MailItem

Dim replyEmail As MailItem

Dim INC1 As String  'For Serial Number

Dim INo As Integer  'For Serial Number

Dim LOC1 As String  'For Location

Dim LoC As Integer  'For Location

Dim SUMM As String  'For Summary

Dim Sum As Integer  'For Summary

Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.item(1)

Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("H:\Documents\Test P1-.oft")

replyEmail.CC = ""

replyEmail.HtmlBody = replyEmail.HtmlBody & origEmail.Reply.HtmlBody

INC1 = origEmail.Subject

INo = InStr(1, INC1, "SR2")

LOC1 = origEmail.Subject

LoC= InStr(1, LOC1, "|") + 10

SUMM= origEmail.Subject

Sum= InStr(1, SUMM, "Summary") + 30

replyEmail.Subject = " <P1> - " & INC1

replyEmail.HtmlBody = Replace(replyEmail.HtmlBody, "INC1", INC1)

replyEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Now I would like to fetch information from body of the email. Below is the format of body of the email.

```
Serial Number: SR23443354
Location: Canada
Summary: Replacement request
```

I need above information to be replaced with my **`.otf`** Template. So when I run the script it should auto populate or replace required field.

Template Body:

```
Serial Number: INC1
Location: LOC
Summary: SUMM
```

When  I tried replacing `origEmail.Subject` with `origEmail.body` its giving me entire email in scattered format.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you

Comment: Not sure if anybody can help me on this to fetch the matter from body of the email. Now i am trying to fetch information from body of the email. I can fetch SR# & Issue from subject but location and summary information  is on the body of the email which i can include.

Comment: okay let me try - what is the information you are getting from the subject, can you show your email subject line?

Comment: The subject lines is SR23443354|Replacement request. From where currently I am fetching information i am fetching information. Now I would like to fetch information from body of the email Like created and location. Below is the format of email.

Subject: SR23443354|Replacement request

A Service request is  assigned to SD team for resolution. Below are the details:

Incident Number:  SR23443354

Company:        ABC Company

Created:               2017-03-01 10:28:07

Summary:       Replacement request for laptop charger

Location:               Canada

Comment: Hi 0m3r, could you plz help me with this.

Comment: Okay again if your subject line is `SR23443354|Replacement request` what will the template subject line be? just `SR23443354` ? or `bla bla SR23443354`

Comment: Yes, it should be Bla- Bla service requested | SR23443354 - Open

Comment: Okay i guess we are friends now  :-) see my answer

Comment: Off course, we are friends mate. Thank you for your help. I will definitely run the below script and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change **`ActiveWindow`** With **`ActiveExplorer`**

*[MSDN Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx)*

*[MSDN Replace Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx)*

*[MSDN InStr Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)*

```
Option Explicit
Sub InitialNotif()
    Dim OrigEmail As MailItem
    Dim ReplyEmail As MailItem
    Dim vText As Variant
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim SerialNum As String
    Dim Location As String
    Dim Summary As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No Item selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set OrigEmail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Set ReplyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Temp\Untitled.oft")

    '// for the Subject
    '// SR23443354|Replacement request = Bla Bla SR23443354|- Open
    ReplyEmail.Subject = "Bla Bla " & "|" _
                                    & Split(OrigEmail.Subject, "|")(0) _
                                    & " - Open"

    '// Process Mail body
    '// Get the text of the message
    '// and split it by paragraph
    vText = Split(OrigEmail.Body, Chr(13)) ' Chr(13)) carriage return

'    '// Check each line of text in the message body
    For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1

        '// locate the text relating to the item required
        '// Serial Number:
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Serial Number") > 0 Then
            '// Split text line From ":"
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58)) '  Chr(58) = :
            SerialNum = vItem(1)
            Debug.Print SerialNum  ' Print Immediate Window
        End If

        '// Location:
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Location") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            Location = vItem(1)
        End If

        '// Summary:
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Summary") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            Summary = vItem(1)
        End If
    Next

'    '// Now Update oft file
    With ReplyEmail
        .Body = Replace(.Body, "INC1", SerialNum)
        .Body = Replace(.Body, "LOC", Location)
        .Body = Replace(.Body, "SUMM", Summary)
    End With

    ReplyEmail.CC = ""
    ReplyEmail.Display

    Set OrigEmail = Nothing
    Set ReplyEmail = Nothing
End Sub
```